# JQuery Submit Hidden Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I know this is simple but I can't figure it out today and I can't find the right solution.

I have a series of tabs which populate data. At the end is a confirmation tab. At this point they can click a 'submit' button. When this button is pressed a hidden form is populated with all the relevant data. I'd like this form to then be submitted but I can't figure out how to submit the form with JQUery. I've attempted to do a trigger on the button but perhaps I'm doing it wrong. Below is a sample of the code for the button taht gets clicked. Note the values populate, I just can't get the form to submit

```
  $('#submitAppointment').click(function() {
        $("#" + formName + "schedule_id option[value='" + $("input[name='appointmentTime']:checked").val() + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');      
        $("#" + formName + "apt_date").val($("#confirmDate").text());
        $("#" + formName + "first_name").val($("#confirmFirstName").text());
        $("#" + formName + "last_name").val($("#confirmLastName").text());
        $("#" + formName + "email").val($("#confirmEmail").text());
        $("#" + formName + "phone").val($("#confirmPhone").text());
        $("#" + formName + "notes").val($("#confirmNotes").text());
        $('#appt_form').submit(function() {
            alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Any ideas on what I'd need to do to rigger the submit function?

Comment: You sure you've used appt_form for the id and not the name? ;) Also I'd drop return false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
$('#appt_form').submit();
```

Don't return `false` from the handler function if you want the form submission to actually proceed. If your intention is to have the form post without the page refreshing, then you're talking about an ajax operation for which you could use `$.post()`.  (It's not clear that that's what you want to do however.)

Comment: Not trying ajax just straight through submit. I'll try just the submit(). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the form you want to submit is found by the `#appt_form` selector, just use [.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) in the no-argument form (which is simply an alias for `.trigger('submit')`)

```
$('#appt_form').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try calling

`$('#appt_form').submit()`

if appt_form is your form id. That command should submit the form, based on jQuery documentation.

Here is [jQuery submit function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)